# PowerShell remoting from a Windows service

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a Windows service that regulary runs a PowerShell script on a remote computer via `WsManConnectionInfo`/`RunspaceFactory` (following the steps from this article: [Remotely Executing Commands in PowerShell using C#](http://com2kid.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/remotely-executing-commands-in-powershell-using-c/)):

```
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, server, 5985, "/wsman",
                                             "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell",
                                             cred)
                        {
                            OperationTimeout = 4*60*1000,
                            OpenTimeout = 1*60*1000
                        };
using (var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
{
    runSpace.Open();
    using (var p = runSpace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        p.Commands.AddScript(script);
        var output = p.Invoke();
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, if I run the Windows service itself with an *Administrator account*, all is well. But if i run the service with the LocalSystem account, I get the following exception;

```
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException:
    Connecting to remote server NOSRVDEV02 failed with the following error message :
        WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with
        errorcode 0x8009030d occurred while using Negotiate authentication:
        A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

    Possible causes are:
        -The user name or password specified are invalid.
        -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
        -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
        -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
        -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.

    After checking for the above issues, try the following:
        -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
        -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
         Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
        -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RunspacePoolInternal.EndOpen(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace.Open()
    ...
```

Note: This has nothing to do with the credentials in `WSManConnectionInfo` - just the account settings in the service properties "Log On" tab.

I don't want to give the service admin privileges. Any ideas why the LocalSystem user fails to log in?

Additional info:

- The remote computer is not a member of a domain.
- I have tried to connect both by IP address and hostname (both are listed in the local computer's `TrustedHosts`).

**EDIT:** Even more info (summary of the comments):

- Local computer: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit (virtual machine on a Windows 8 box).
- Remote computer: Windows Server 2008R2 Datacenter 64bit.
- The main reason we don't want to change service user accounts is that this is an update to an old service which is already deployed on many clients (customers).
- The service also accesses the Windows registry and the file system on the local computer, so setting the user account to something *more restricted*, like NetworkService, would just open a different can of worms.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running this on?

Comment: @mjolinor - Local computer: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit (virtual machine on a Windows 8 box). Remote computer: Windows Server 2008R2 Datacenter 64bit.

Comment: Have you tried using the NetworkService account instead of the LocalSystem account?

Comment: @mjolinor - thanks for your time! The service also reads from/writes to the Windows registry, so if I use NetworkService I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when (re)starting the service..

Comment: You should be able to fix that in the registry permissions.

Comment: When you say `I don't want to give the service admin privileges` do you mean on the computer *running* the service or the computer you're remoting into? Assuming the latter, is there any reason why you can't create an account on the target computer that does not have administrator privileges that's dedicated for this purpose? How are you specifying the LocalSystem account? Have you tried `ComputerName\LocalSystem`? Something seems odd to me to try to log in as the LocalSystem account from a remote computer.

Comment: Also please note that the LocalSystem account has many more privileges that you seem to indicate or want here. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx): The LocalSystem account "has extensive privileges on the local computer, and acts as the computer on the network. Its token includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs; these accounts have access to most system objects."

Comment: @tnw - On the computer running the service (local computer). This is an update to an existing service which is deployed on many clients (customers), so I was hoping to keep using the LocalSystem account.

Comment: @Sphinxxx Yeah, LocalSystem is not what you are looking for then. That actually has a lot more privileges than you realize. The MSDN page I linked even has a great bit that's very relevant to this: "Most services do not need such a high privilege level. If your service does not need these privileges, and it is not an interactive service, consider using the LocalService account or the NetworkService account. For more information, see Service Security and Access Rights." You should further investigate mjolinor's suggestion of the NetworkService account.

Comment: @tnw - Thanks for the info :) If all else fails, I guess we'll have to change the service's account after all..

Comment: @mjolinor - Are you saying that there is no way for `LocalSystem` to log on to the remote server? I will try to up the permissions on NetworkService. Do you have any links/documentation on how to do that? (sorry, user accounts and/or security is not my strong suit..)

Comment: The NetWorkService account was introduced specifically for accessing remote systems.  It has mimimal rights on the local system, so you have to explicitly grant whatever additional rughts it needs.  The LocalSystem account has a lot more rights on the local system granted by default, a lot of which you don't need for whatever this service is doing. I believe the intent is to encourage "good practice" in limiting the permissions that accounts used for connecting to remote systems have to just what's required.

Comment: @mjolinor - Then shouldn't LocalSystem (because it has all those rights) also be able to access remote systems? Or would it at least be possible to grant it permissions to do so?

Comment: It's intended for local system maintenance tasks, so it has a lot of rights granted to the local system. Whether it can access a remote system is determined by permissions set on the remote system.

Comment: @mjolinor - Again, thanks for your help on this! Could you elaborate on how the permissions on the remote system would have to be changed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A rather surprising solution to this one: The username in the `PSCredential` object (`cred`) needed to be prefixed with the domain-less remote computer's name, e.g. "**MYREMOTESERVERNAME\remoteusername**" and not just "**remoteusername**".

I have no idea why the prefix is needed only when connecting with the LocalSystem account though...

Comment: Thanks. I have been struggling with the exact same problem for days, and this helped. Did you discover the solution by chance, or is there some source for this information ?

Comment: @Cozzamara - It was simply a suggestion from a colleague, so I'm afraid I don't have any more information for you :)

Comment: Thanks for solution, also I could add that in MYREMOTESERVERNAME I tried computer name and it didn't worked, but then I tried MYREMOTESERVERIPADDRESS\remoteusername and it worked.

Comment: I ran into this issue while running "Invoke-Command" inside a PowerShell script (worked fine directly on the CLI). I found that I only had to add the backslash, eg ``\remoteusername``. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: for me just adding '\' before username in PSCredential object worked.
eg `\remoteusername`

Comment: I am using `.\remoteusername` which looks slightly more familiar. Anyway, thanks for the great hint!

Comment: You are a life saver men. It worked after prefixing the server name. Interesting thing is, it worked without server name prefix, if I run it directly in powershell console.